# Finding the difference between 2 columns and printing on a 3rd

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm attempting to write a script that subtracts cells in Column C from Column B and prints the result in Column D.

Column B holds variables that are changed periodically (roughly 2x per hour) (I do not control this API and its imported from outside. Im not sure when exactly they're updated.

Those Values are copied from Column B to Column C as static numbers every hour.

I havent programmed in well over 10 years and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work, so I hope I'll be able to get some answers here.

```
function domath(o) {
  var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var a = aa.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
  var m = a.getRange("B1:B3200");
  var n = a.getRange("C1:C3200");
  var o = m-n;
  var targetRange = a.getRange("D1:D3200");
  
  o.copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly: true});
 
}


function copyColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
  var sourceRange = s.getRange("B1:B3");
  var targetRange = s.getRange("C1:C3");
  
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with a more complete example. Are you getting any errors? How are you trying to invoke these functions? Is there a reason you can't use the native formula `=B2-C2` in D2 and drag that down to fill the column instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to subtract the cells in Column C from Column B and print the result in Column D, you can use the below snippet:

#### Snippet

```
function domath() {
   var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var a = aa.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
   var m = a.getRange("B1:B3200").getValues();
   var n = a.getRange("C1:C3200").getValues();
   var o = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      o[i] = m[i] - n[i];
      a.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue(o[i]);
   }
}
```

#### Explanation

In order to be able to **retrieve** the values from a range, you have to make use of the `getValues()` function. Therefore, after the values from the `B` and `C` columns have been gathered, an empty array `o` has been created. A `for` has been used to loop through the values from the arrays (since both have the same dimension) and the difference of each element has been calculated and added into the array. As for setting the result of this into the `D` column, the `getRange` and `setValue` methods have been used.

#### Suggestion

Since you have mentioned that the values in the `B` column are imported, you can make use of a time-based installable trigger which will be attached to the above function and will trigger its execution one time a day for example.

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('domath')
       .timeBased()
       .everyDays(1)
       .atHour(9)
       .create();
}
```

#### Note

Please bear in mind that you can customize the trigger in order to suit your needs accordingly.

#### Reference

- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [ClockTriggerBuilder Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder);
- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Range Class Apps Script - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
- [Range Class Apps Script - setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues);
- [Range Class Apps Script - setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).

Comment: This worked! Thanks a bunch! Im using google's trigger mechanism to handle the hourly triggering. Thanks again